# Specific FCM topic messages aren't received in app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've started with `topic 'a'`, which worked just fine.
After a day or two I tried to send another message and noticed the topic `a` messages are no longer received.
I've added a subscription call to a new topic, `b` right below the topic `a` subscription, and the topic `b` messages received with no issues.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("a");
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("b");
```

I've also made sure there is no 'unsubscribe' call anywhere.
I've tried sending messages using both Firebase Console & Post requests according to the HTTP api, both worked for topic `b` and didn't work for topic `a`.

How can I debug this ?  (The messages doesn't get to the device..)

Answer (score 0):

You can see what subscriptions exist at the server for a device using this CURL command:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=<yourServerKey>" 
     --header "Content-Type: application/json"
     https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/<deviceToken>?details=true
```

where: `<yourServerKey>` is available from the Firebase Console project settings for Cloud Messaging, and `<deviceToken>` is the 152-char token returned by `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` ([documentation here](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances)).

Are you calling `subscribeToTopic()` everytime your app initializes?

I'm pretty confident that a subscription is no longer valid if the device token changes.  During your testing did anything cause the [device ID](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId) or token to change after you subscribed for topic 'a'?

Comment: I didn't continue to investigate the issue, I just changed the topic name from  `a` to `a1` and everything works.  Most likely this is a server/service issue.